# How to make qgis custom plugin stop running after quit?

Tags: plugins, pyqgis

I developed a custom `QGIS` plugin docked on main window.
The main function of the plugin is detecting layer change event and display properties of the layer.

The plugin works fine but I found it still running even after I quit the plugin.
The plugin is closed when the 'x' on the dock widget.

Is there any solution I can stop running plugin after quit?